# Errors while updating Meteor version

Tags: meteor, compiler-errors, package, upgrade

I am trying to update my meteor project from 1.8.2 to the latest version. To do this, I have run `meteor update` outside of a meteor project and got this message:

`The latest version of Meteor, 2.3.6, is already installed on this computer. Run 'meteor update' inside of a particular project directory to update that project to Meteor 2.3.6`

After that, I go into my project directory and run the same `meteor update` and receive this message:

```
=> Errors while initializing project:         
                                              
While selecting package versions:
error: No version of standard-minifier-js satisfies all constraints: @2.6.1, @=2.5.0, @~2.6.1
Constraints on package "standard-minifier-js":
* standard-minifier-js@2.6.1 <- top level
* standard-minifier-js@=2.5.0 <- top level
* standard-minifier-js@~2.6.1 <- top level

No version of babel-compiler satisfies all constraints: @=7.4.0, @~7.7.0
Constraints on package "babel-compiler":
* babel-compiler@=7.4.0 <- top level
* babel-compiler@~7.7.0 <- top level
* babel-compiler@7.7.0 <- ecmascript 0.15.3 <- 416serg:simple-text-rotator 0.0.1
```

I'm not too clear on what the above error message means so if someone could explain that would be amazing. Even better if you've got any tips or ideas to solve this. Please let me know if you need any additional information!

As requested in comment, `.meteor/packages`:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

# autopublish
# insecure
accounts-ui@1.3.1
accounts-password@1.5.1
# documentation for iron router talks about a higher version.
# but, example todos and others use 0.9.4 which uses routes without a slash(/),
# and actual url is specified on path property.
iron:router@=0.9.4
jquery
underscore@1.0.10
email@1.2.3
alanning:roles
meteor-base@1.4.0
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mongo@1.7.0
blaze-html-templates
session@1.2.0
tracker@1.2.0
logging@1.1.20
reload@1.3.0
random@1.1.0
ejson@1.1.0
spacebars
check@1.3.1
matb33:collection-hooks
# for stripe mrgalaxy:stripe
mrgalaxy:stripe
momentjs:moment
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
http@1.4.2
# for theme
less
twbs:bootstrap@3.3.5
fortawesome:fontawesome
reactive-var@1.0.11
summernote:summernote
dsyko:meteor-node-csv
#force-ssl
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal
416serg:simple-text-rotator
risul:bootstrap-colorpicker
tomi:upload-jquery
dangrossman:bootstrap-daterangepicker
hellotech:moment-timezone
agnito:simptip
#abhiaiyer:meteor-twilio
jercle:livestamp
#msavin:mongol

tmeasday:publish-counts
kadira:blaze-layout
standard-minifier-css@1.5.4
standard-minifier-js@2.6.1
shell-server@0.4.0
dynamic-import@0.5.1
tomi:upload-server@1.3.4_3
tsega:mentions
montiapm:agent
mizzao:autocomplete
huaming:js-xlsx
edgee:slingshot
mizzao:user-status
```

I also have a file `.meteor/packages~` (not sure what this is or if it's relevant):

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
# Check this file (and the other files in this directory) into your repository.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

# autopublish
# insecure
accounts-ui
accounts-password
# documentation for iron router talks about a higher version.
# but, example todos and others use 0.9.4 which uses routes without a slash(/),
# and actual url is specified on path property.
iron:router@=0.9.4
jquery
underscore
email
alanning:roles
standard-minifiers
meteor-base
mobile-experience
mongo
blaze-html-templates
session
tracker
logging
reload
random
ejson
spacebars
check
# for stripe mrgalaxy:stripe
mrgalaxy:stripe
momentjs:moment
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
http
# for theme
less
twbs:bootstrap@3.3.5
fortawesome:fontawesome
reactive-var
summernote:summernote

dsyko:meteor-node-csv
#force-ssl
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal
416serg:simple-text-rotator
risul:bootstrap-colorpicker
tomi:upload-server

tomi:upload-jquery
dangrossman:bootstrap-daterangepicker
```

Comment: What is the exact content of your `.meteor/packages` project file?

Comment: Try to run `meteor Update --all-packages` to update all package including dependents.

Comment: So I'm not sure when/how but it now says that the project is running meteor 2.3.6 but running ```meteor update --all-packages``` gives the same error as above but now with 2 more packages it's complaining about

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have all of these in your top-level, i.e., `.meteor/packages`:

```
babel-compiler@=7.4.0
babel-compiler@~7.7.0
standard-minifier-js@2.6.1
standard-minifier-js@=2.5.0
standard-minifier-js@~2.6.1
```

which express version constraints on the named packages. There are no versions for these two packages that satisfy all given constraints. But it seems pretty safe to say that you can reduce this to:

```
babel-compiler@~7.7.0
standard-minifier-js@2.6.1
```

but if

```
babel-compiler@~7.7.0
standard-minifier-js@~2.6.1
```

works, that would probably save you some trouble down the road, so I would try that first.

If you want to learn more about these constraint expressions, they are Semantic Versioning constraints, i.e., the same as used by npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but after checking the files in my ```.meteor``` directory, I do not have ```babel-compiler``` in my ```.meteor/packages```, however I do have it in ```.meteor/versions (babel-compiler@7.7.0)```. Maybe this is the problem and I have to add it to ```.meteor/packages```?

Comment: Nope, adding it to ```.meteor/packages``` just added another line to the error

Comment: do you also have `babel-compiler@=7.4.0` in the versions file?

Comment: you can also try to delete (move way) your versions file and let meteor regenerate it. I would keep a backup though in case that doesn't help.

Comment: Nope I've got ```babel-compiler@7.7.0``` and ```babel-runtime@1.4.0``` in the versions file but I'll try removing the versions file and letting meteor regenerate

Comment: So what I did is completely removed my ```~/.meteor```, ```project/.meteor```, created a new meteor project with ```meteor create```, moved all of the source code into the new meteor project and re-added packages to fix the errors as they came up. Not a greatly efficient method but I've got the project running on 2.3.6 now so I'm happy